# How can I clear chrome browser state in between every test?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to get a fresh instance of selenium chrome browser before every test that I run. I can achieve this by doing driver.quit() after every test and then initializing a new instance, but this is time consuming and resource intensive. Seems like there needs to be a better way, but I haven't been able to find anything online.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
@AfterMethod
public void shutDown(){
   seleniumDriver.quit();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void start(){
    seleniumDriver = SeleniumExtensions.createDefaultWebDriver();
}
```

Ultimately, instead of quitting and getting new instancem I would just be able to do something like this, where getFreshInstance clears the state (cookies, cache, session, etc):

```
 @AfterMethod
    public void cleanDriver(){
       seleniumDriver.getFreshInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cookies:

```
seleniumDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Selenium doesn't offer a method of deleting cache, natively. Per [this blog post](https://learn2seleniumwithvishwas.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/selenium-webdriver-script-to-clear-browser-history-in-chrome/), you could try this for clearing the cache:

```
WebElement clearDataBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm"));
if(sync.isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm"))){
System.out.println("Clear button found");
clearDataBtn.click();
}
```

Comment: That's in the right direction, +1; there's one more component to take care of - [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), e.g. `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.